# Spring-boot: register mongodb custom converter

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using this dependency into my spring bott service:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I've created a custom converter:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

@Component
public class ReferenceWriterConverter implements Converter<Reference, DBObject> {
    @Override
    public DBObject convert(Reference reference) {
        DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
        //...
        return dbObject;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to "register" this converter. However, diving over there I don't quite figure out whether I need to use a `CustomConvertions` class or `MappingMongoConverter`.

How would I need to "register" my custom converter into my spring boot service?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the customConversions of mongodb, like so:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions(){
        List<Converter<?,?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(ReferenceWriterConverter.INSTANCE);
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }

    @WritingConverter
    enum ReferenceWriterConverter implements Converter<Reference, DBObject> {

        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public String convert(Reference reference) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can also declare the converter in your separate class like above and just autowire it into the configuration.

Comment: What's `MappingMongoConverter` meant for?

Comment: This is used by spring-mongodb to map between mongodb documents and your entities as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MappingMongoConverter.html. This bean is autonfigured if using Spring Boot.
 You could override it if you need to alter it. In your case, you just want to add additional converters, so you don't want to alter the general mechanism for mapping I guess.

Comment: Ok, I'd like to test this. I mean I like to test if custom converters runs well on a unit test. I don't know how to inject these converts into `MongoDbTemplate`. Is there anyway injection is made automatically? I don't know if I've explained so well. Any ideas?

Comment: With this Bean `customConversions`, you are basically overriding the custom conversions for the mongo configuration, as is specified here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/MongoConfigurationSupport.html. So this conversions are automatically injected in a `mongoTemplate` for example. I hope, I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I meant how could I inject these custom converters into my junit test classes. I don't know how to test them...

Comment: Do you want to test the converter alone or in the Spring lifecycle. For the first, you can basically just instantiate it in your test and for the latter you can autowire it in your test if you use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` (Junit 4) or `SpringExtension` (Junit 5)

Comment: I'm interested in both, xD. I've edited post with current test code. Could you provide a straightforward example?

Comment: Could you add that code snippet in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438558/spring-boot-testing-custom-mongodbtemplate-converters ? Because I think this makes it cleaner to have one question per issue and also is better for formatting I guess

Comment: I've just added this code snippet on these question.