# Spring Boot: Testing custom MongoTemplate converters

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using this custom converters into my Spring Boot service:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

        @Bean
        public MongoCustomConversions customConversions(){
            List<Converter<?,?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
            converters.add(ReferenceWriterConverter.INSTANCE);
            return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
        }

        @WritingConverter
        enum ReferenceWriterConverter implements Converter<Reference, DBObject> {

            INSTANCE;

            @Override
            public String convert(Reference reference) {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Into my controllers, I'm using `MontoTemplate` in order to talk with MongoDB. So, all converters are already loaded into template.

However, I'd like to test `MongoDbTemplate` using Spring injection features. I mean, I want to test `MongoDbTemplate` using custom converters which should already be loaded.

Any ideas on how it can be achieved?

**EDIT**

```
public class ModelTest {

    private List<Reference> references;

    public ModelTest() {
        this.references = new ArrayList<Reference>();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.setId("Ref1");
        reference.setTimestamp(new Date());

        Metadata met = new Metadata();
        met.setId("Mdt1");
        met.setUser("user");
        met.setCreationTimestamp(new Date());

        met.setMetadata("[{'departament': 'JUST'}]");

        reference.setMetadata(met);

        this.references.add(reference);

        ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress);
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "db");

        mongoTemplate.insert(reference);
    }

    /**
     * Assert Office mime type documents.
     */
    @Test
    public void office() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I also would like to use custom testing properties. I mean, currently, we are setting properties into `src/test/resources/application.properties`.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host: localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port: 27017
```

How could I load these file properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

If you want to test it with the Spring context, you can annotate your Test class as `SpringBootTest` and autowire the `MongoTemplate`. This should then contain your custom conversions for you to test them:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ModelTest {

    private List<Reference> references;

    @Autowired
    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public ModelTest() {
        this.references = new ArrayList<Reference>();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.setId("Ref1");
        reference.setTimestamp(new Date());

        Metadata met = new Metadata();
        met.setId("Mdt1");
        met.setUser("user");
        met.setCreationTimestamp(new Date());

        met.setMetadata("[{'departament': 'JUST'}]");

        reference.setMetadata(met);

        this.references.add(reference);

        mongoTemplate.insert(reference);
    }

    /**
     * Assert Office mime type documents.
     */
    @Test
    public void office() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

If you just want to test the converter alone, you could make a `ReferenceWriterConverterTest` like so:

```
public class ReferenceWriterConverterTest {

    private ReferenceWriterConverter converter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        converter = ReferenceWriterConverter.INSTANCE;
    }

    //test stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael. Currently, I have two questions:
 1. I would like to get now how to load custom test properties (I've edited post).
 2. Where is `@SpringBootTest` is located (dependency)?

Comment: No problem :) 1) These properties should automatically be used for your `MongoTemplate` if you use the `SpringBootTest`. 2) It is part of `spring-boot-starter-test`: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test

Comment: Solved. It's getting an `Failed to load ApplicationContext` right now. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace? I guess the Spring application context can't be initialized because of a missing configuration or something like that

Comment: I've detailed the issue on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440760/spring-test-exclude-resources-from-applicationcontext)