# Builder pattern when retrieving entity from DB w/ spring boot reactor & mongo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok, spring-mongodb

I have the following bean that describes a mongo document, and that uses lombok:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyClass.MyClassBuilder.class)
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Value
public class MyClass {

    private final String id;

    @Default
    private final String field = "defaultValue";

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class MyClassBuilder {}
}
```

When deserializing `{"id": "document"}` with jackson, I end-up with a bean containing both `id=document` and `field=defaultValue` because it used the builder that provide a default value for the field.

Now what I want to do, is to have the defaultValue set for documents coming out of the database (coming from `ReactiveMongoTemplate`). But it seems to use the all args constructor even if I set it private (or some reflect black magic)

So the main question is: is it possible to tell spring to use the builder to build the bean when coming out of the database?

Comment: how about a custom converter? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438230/spring-boot-register-mongodb-custom-converter

Comment: @Tiler, can you please try the below and see if that helps?
`@Builder.Default
private String field = "defaultValue";`

Answer (score 2):

- You are not going to be able to use your custom serialiser because when I go through the source code of `MappingMongoConverter` in spring mongodb (debugged it with a sample app) , I see only the following steps.
- Once the value from db is available as `org.bson.Document`, `MappingMongoConverter.java` is looking to create your entity object.
- First, it checks if you have any custom converters registered and if you have it, then use it. So one option is to use a custom converter registered.
- If there is no custom converters registered, it goes and find the `PersistenceConstructor` and use it. I had an object with 3 constructors (no param, one param, and all param) and it chose my no param constructor.
- However, if I annotate a constructor with `@PersistenceConstructor`, it is choosing that constructor. So could follow this approach but then you have to keep `String field` un-initialised and getting initialised differently in each constructor
- `MappingMongoConverter.java`

  - [conversions.hasCustomReadTarget](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MappingMongoConverter.java#L262)
  - [persistenceConstructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MappingMongoConverter.java#L337)